# What is the mathematical expresion for a combination in which repetitions occur in a certain order, and how to save all combinations into an array

Tags: matlab, math, combinations

I am trying to write some code that outputs all the possible variations of pit lap strategies for a race. Say the race is 6 laps long, and during that time 3 pit stops are made, the possible combinations are:
111123
111223
112223
122223
122233
etc ....
where 1, 2 and 3 are just being used to visualize when the pit stops have been made. I have been searching for a mathematical function that outputs the total number of variations possible but to no avail, does anyone know?

Furthermore, is there a way to create an array that contains all of the different combinations displaying how many 1, 2 and 3s are in the combination?

Thank you

Comment: Please explain better. You speak about "combinations", then "variationS", and repetitions are allowed, which is confusing. What's the exact rule for creating all possible results? Is it all Cartesian tuples such the numbers in each tuple are non-decreasing?

Comment: Have a look at [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). Is the first pit stop always taken on lap 1? Are all 3 pit stops always taken by lap 6?

Comment: @beaker Ah, it's probably that :-) I couldn't make much sense of the description

Comment: @LuisMendo I think that each position corresponds to lap 1 through 6 from left to right, and the value is the number of pit stops taken by that lap.

Comment: @LuisMendo yeah, I had to read it a few times.

Comment: I apologize for fo the poor phrasing, I'll try to explain it better now. Basically, I am trying to figure out all the possible combinations where a car could pit in a race when that race has a defined number of laps and a defined number of pit stops. Say the race is 10 laps long and the car will pit 3 times;  the car could pit once on the first lap, again on the second, and have its last pit stop on the third lap and finish the race after.  Similarly, it could race two laps before pitting, then another two before pitting again and have its last pit stop on lap 9 etc...

Comment: What im trying to figure out is how many of those combinations there are (mathematically) and then how to store that information in an array.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it seems like these are the conditions: 6 laps. 3 mandatory pit stops, but there are no rules on when the first one can be taken. The numbers [1,2,3] are arbitrary and what you really want is to simulate the pitstop positions? Does something like, `nchoosek(1:6,3)` (where the rows in the output matrix are the combinations of lap position), satisfy your requirements? Encoding positions to your format might be a little less obvious, but not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a question about combinatorics and encoding the result in an array. From a programming (MATLAB) perspective, the answer to "how many combinations" is `nchoosek(nLaps,nPitstops)`. Briefly, since the ordering is irrelevant, i.e., pit stops are the same regardless of when they are taken, the answer to the counting question is solved using the [binomial therom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). If you have 6 laps and 3 of them will contain a pit stop, then you get "6 choose 3" possible combinations.

For the array part of the question, MATLAB has taken care of the 'hard' work of determining all the combinations by allowing us to input a vector to produce the combinations. An approach to the problem could be the following:

```matlab
% initialize
nLaps = 6;
nPitstops = 3;
laps = 1:nLaps;
pits = 1:nPitstops;

% calculate binomial coefficient
b = nchoosek(nLaps,nPitstops);
% generate combinations
C = nchoosek(laps,nPitstops);

% create solution matrix
result = ones(b,nLaps);
% loop through each combination
for B = 1:b
  % loop through the pit identifiers
  for P = pits
    % determine the start lap
    start = C(B,P);
    % determine the next start lap...
    if P < pits(end)
      stop = C(B,P+1);
    else
      % ... or simply repeat until end
      stop = nLaps;
    end
    % store pit identifier in these lap positions
    result(B,start:stop) = P;
  end
end
```

The above code will produce:

```
result =
     1     2     3     3     3     3
     1     2     2     3     3     3
     1     2     2     2     3     3
     1     2     2     2     2     3
     1     1     2     3     3     3
     1     1     2     2     3     3
     1     1     2     2     2     3
     1     1     1     2     3     3
     1     1     1     2     2     3
     1     1     1     1     2     3
     1     1     2     3     3     3
     1     1     2     2     3     3
     1     1     2     2     2     3
     1     1     1     2     3     3
     1     1     1     2     2     3
     1     1     1     1     2     3
     1     1     1     2     3     3
     1     1     1     2     2     3
     1     1     1     1     2     3
     1     1     1     1     2     3
```

I am a little confused by your desired notation. In the case where the first pit stop is made after the first lap, e.g., `112333`, using your notation, I would expect a `0` in the first lap position, like this: `012333`, since there has not yet been a pit stop. If that is a notation you desire, then you would initialize the `result` variable with the `zeros()` function instead.